# Debian with iptables and fail2ban not ban IP

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, fail2ban

I have server with Debian 9.
I have installed fail2ban and configured it. It work with sshd (ban IP on failed logins) but i can't make it work with apache-auth (IP is ban but iptables don't block it).

jail.local look like:

```
[DEFAULT]
bantime  = 720h
findtime  = 60m
banaction = iptables
mta = sendmail
destemail = my-email@example.com
action = %(action_mw)s
maxretry = 2

[sshd]
enabled = true

[apache-auth]
enabled = true
```

When i run compand:

```
fail2ban-client status sshd
```

it show banned IP. 
When i run command:

```
iptables -L -n
```

It show IPs from previous command. So it's working correct.

When i run:

```
fail2ban-client status apache-auth
```

It show ban IP (me).

```
iptables -L -n
```

Don't show any IP from previous list. 
Can be important iptables shows:

```
Chain f2b-apache-auth (0 references)
```

And i still can connect to server via WWW. Exactly same issue i had with nginx so i switched to apache, i was thinking this will solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

My jail.conf part for apache looks a bit different

```
[apache]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-auth
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 6
```

You can find the loaded configuration with

```
fail2ban-client -d
```

You said you are testing locally. Make sure your IP not in the netmask given in `ignoreip`.

As the action is probably triggered in your case have a look for the entry `actionban` there and see if it actually adds the desired iptables rule.

Maybe `var/log/fail2ban.log` has more information?

Comment: yes there was but i was not able to find log for longer time :D
After i have get it, it was quite easy :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution!

```
[apache-auth]
enabled = true
action   = iptables-multiport[port="http,https"]
port     = http,https
```

'action' was missing. fail2ban was sending port range and iptables was expecting single port... after adding such "action" all is working great.

So we can say it's solved.

@Jonas Eberle - your config is in all tutorials, unfortunately was also not working :(

Comment: If this is solved, please mark it as solved by clicking the outline of the tick mark so that it turns solid green.